# Extracting Maven error message in script

Tags: maven

As part of the CI flow, I have a script that runs maven and reports the result to another system, based on exit codes.

It would be much nicer if I can also send some error message, in case some error did happen.

It appears that Maven does have some concept of "bottom line error message", that is shown after the summary phase. Is there any simple way to extract that message?

Answer (score 0):

Enable email on failure option. You will get a mail with error specified [full stacktrace]

Comment: Enable it where? Does maven has built-in email support? Will I need a separate script to receive, the email, parse it, and report?

Comment: In the CI, if you use Jenkins, there is an option in job settings to receive emails on build failure

Comment: That's technically correct, but doesn't answer any part of my question. I'm trying to get the error message from maven into the script running it.

Comment: You can't achieve this. Maven will not pass just the error msg  to any script. If you want complete output including error to be stored in file then you can achieve this.

Comment: The closest you could get is probably the `EventSpy` (bad documented) but it is not simple.